# AWS S3 multipart upload with raw bytes instead of File

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create multipart upload, however i am recieving raw data, not file, and in examples in documentation multipart request requires File, not data e.g

```
UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucketName)
        .withKey(key)
        .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
        .withPartNumber(part) // parts start with 1
        .withFileOffset(filePosition)
        .withFile(filePath.toFile())
        .withPartSize(partSize);
UploadPartResult uploadPartResult = amazonS3.uploadPart(uploadRequest);
partETags.add(uploadPartResult.getPartETag());
```

Is there any way how to pot raw byes into the UploadPartRquest? Something like

```
byte[] data = getData();
UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucketName)
        .withKey(key)
        .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
        .withPartNumber(part) // parts start with 1
        .withFileOffset(filePosition)
        .withData(data)
        .withPartSize(partSize);
UploadPartResult uploadPartResult = amazonS3.uploadPart(uploadRequest);
partETags.add(uploadPartResult.getPartETag());
```

Or am i stuck with creating temp file, sending it to request object and then deleting said file?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's [a `withInputStream` method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/UploadPartRequest.html#withInputStream-java.io.InputStream-) and you can always create an `InputStream` from a byte array via [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html). Combined I think that'll do what you want.

Comment: does it need and wrapping in order to ensure all bytes has been sent, or just passing inputStream is enough?